# Installed R packages in Dockerfile won't be found when running container

Tags: python, r, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to install several R packages in a Python Docker image. I've this small `Dockerfile`:

```
# Python 3.7.5
FROM python:3.7.5
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install R 3.6
RUN echo 'deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/' >> /etc/apt/sources.list
RUN apt install dirmngr
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y r-base
 
# Install R dependencies
RUN R -e "install.packages('BiocManager', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
```

It doesn't throw any error. But when I run `docker container exec -it <my container> bash` and do:

`Rscript -e 'installed.packages()' | grep BiocManager`

There aren't any results. I don't know if this applies, but during building it throws:

> The downloaded source packages are in
>
> '/tmp/Rtmp7jBLWQ/downloaded_packages'

Maybe that it's installing the packages on a temp folder is the problem. Is there any way to install R packages without making an image base on [R-base](https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base) image and use `install2.r`?

Comment: I don't know, but you might need to check *where* the new package is being installed, with `.libPaths()`. (You can set it in `install.packages(..., lib="/some/path")`.) To know where R will be looking, you might want to first run `docker container exec -it name Rscript -e '.libPaths()'`.

Comment: I like to use the `littler` package to install R packages on Docker images so it throws an error that stops that step in the build process instead of bypassing it. http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html

Comment: https://github.com/ropenscilabs/r-docker-tutorial/issues/41

Comment: Thanks to all of you! I'll give a try and tell you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a shame... I had a docker-compose with a `build: .` clause and I forget to run `docker-compose build`. That's why the changes didn't apply.

However I used the [r-base image](https://hub.docker.com/_/r-base) to install the dependies in an easier way. My final `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM r-base:3.6.2

# Install R dependencies
RUN install2.r --error BiocManager

# Install Python 3.7
RUN apt install -y python3.7 python3-pip
```