# Unable to install and use R packages in Docker (along with Python)

Tags: python, r, docker

I am stuck on this issue and I am new to R.

What is the *correct* way of installing R and Python within Docker? (general approach).

I tried this to run Python and R in a Docker with these Dockerfiles (after checking multiple answers on SO):

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential wget r-base 
python3.10 python3-pip python3-setuptools python3-dev

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN R -e "install.packages('rjson')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('reticulate')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('Robyn')"

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 80

RUN mkdir ~/.streamlit

RUN cp ./config.toml ~/.streamlit/config.toml

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "Scripts/HomePage.py"]
```

---

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential cmake r-base r-base-dev python3.9 \
    python3-pip vim wget libssl-dev \
    libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dev

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt -v

#RUN Rscript -e "install.packages(c('rjson', 'readxl', 'reticulate', 'Robyn'))"

RUN R -e "install.packages('rjson', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('readxl', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('reticulate', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('Robyn', dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.us.r-project.org')"


# http://cran.rstudio.com/

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 80

RUN mkdir ~/.streamlit

RUN cp ./config.toml ~/.streamlit/config.toml

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "Scripts/HomePage.py"]
```

The problem is that when I invoke R script from Streamlit app, the Error 'Robyn' is not available comes up everytime. If I try to install again within the script I get other issues relating to version conflict.

I even tried from `r-base` image from here: [LINK to SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60311313/3903762)

But still no success for running the R code. What am I missing here? Do I need to configure R for something too?

The way I call R script :

```
res = subprocess.call(["Rscript", "Scripts/new-mmm.R"])
```

I am trying to run Robyn demo.R code from here as part of Streamlit app  ([Robyn](https://facebookexperimental.github.io/Robyn/)).

I install `nevergrad` via Python before moving to R package installation and install `reticulate` too before `Robyn`. Even having these as `install.packages("reticulate")` within the script fails to run successfully.

With `r-base` image:

```
FROM r-base:4.2.0

RUN apt-get update && apt install -y python3.10 python3-pip

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN install2.r --error rjson
RUN install2.r --error reticulate
RUN install2.r --error Robyn

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 80

RUN mkdir ~/.streamlit

RUN cp ./config.toml ~/.streamlit/config.toml

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "Scripts/HomePage.py"]
```

For this `Docker build logs`:

```
#8 2134.0 ERROR: dependencies ‘lares’, ‘nloptr’ are not available for package ‘Robyn’
#8 2134.0 * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Robyn’
#8 2134.0
#8 2134.0 The downloaded source packages are in
#8 2134.0       ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
#8 2134.0 Error: installation of package ‘Robyn’ had non-zero exit status
#8 2134.0 In addition: Warning messages:
#8 2134.0 1: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#8 2134.0   installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
#8 2134.0 2: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#8 2134.0   installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
#8 2134.0 3: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#8 2134.0   installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
#8 2134.0 4: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#8 2134.0   installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
#8 2134.0 5: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#8 2134.0   installation of package ‘h2o’ had non-zero exit status
#8 2134.0 6: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#8 2134.0   installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
#8 2134.0 7: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#8 2134.0   installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
#8 2134.0 8: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#8 2134.0   installation of package ‘lares’ had non-zero exit status
#8 2134.0 9: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#8 2134.0   installation of package ‘nloptr’ had non-zero exit status
#8 2134.0 10: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#8 2134.0   installation of package ‘Robyn’ had non-zero exit status
#8 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c install2.r --error Robyn]: exit code: 1
------
 > [5/5] RUN install2.r --error Robyn:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c install2.r --error Robyn]: exit code: 1
```

### **Edit**

I also get this when trying to install directly from R script (within container):

```
2023-04-25 19:55:58 ERROR: dependency ‘lares’ is not available for package ‘Robyn’
2023-04-25 19:55:58 * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Robyn’
2023-04-25 19:55:58 
2023-04-25 19:55:58 The downloaded source packages are in
2023-04-25 19:55:58     ‘/tmp/Rtmp6FgtmT/downloaded_packages’
2023-04-25 19:55:58 Warning messages:
2023-04-25 19:55:58 1: In install.packages("Robyn", configure.args = "--with-ssl=openssl --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",  :
2023-04-25 19:55:58   installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
2023-04-25 19:55:58 2: In install.packages("Robyn", configure.args = "--with-ssl=openssl --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",  :
2023-04-25 19:55:58   installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
2023-04-25 19:55:58 3: In install.packages("Robyn", configure.args = "--with-ssl=openssl --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",  :
2023-04-25 19:55:58   installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
2023-04-25 19:55:58 4: In install.packages("Robyn", configure.args = "--with-ssl=openssl --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",  :
2023-04-25 19:55:58   installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
2023-04-25 19:55:58 5: In install.packages("Robyn", configure.args = "--with-ssl=openssl --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",  :
2023-04-25 19:55:58   installation of package ‘h2o’ had non-zero exit status
2023-04-25 19:55:58 6: In install.packages("Robyn", configure.args = "--with-ssl=openssl --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",  :
2023-04-25 19:55:58   installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
2023-04-25 19:55:58 7: In install.packages("Robyn", configure.args = "--with-ssl=openssl --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",  :
2023-04-25 19:55:58   installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
2023-04-25 19:55:58 8: In install.packages("Robyn", configure.args = "--with-ssl=openssl --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",  :
2023-04-25 19:55:58   installation of package ‘lares’ had non-zero exit status
2023-04-25 19:55:58 9: In install.packages("Robyn", configure.args = "--with-ssl=openssl --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt",  :
2023-04-25 19:55:58   installation of package ‘Robyn’ had non-zero exit status
```

**EDIT**

Using `rocker`:

```
FROM rocker/r-ubuntu

ENV CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST=0
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y --no-install-recommends

RUN apt install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential curl openssl cmake python3.10 python3-pip

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE rjson
RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE reticulate
RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE Robyn

COPY . /app

EXPOSE 80

RUN mkdir ~/.streamlit

RUN cp ./config.toml ~/.streamlit/config.toml

CMD ["streamlit", "run", "Scripts/HomePage.py"]
```

**Error**

```
 ERROR: dependency ‘lares’ is not available for package ‘Robyn’
#13 2077.7 * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Robyn’
#13 2077.7
#13 2077.7 The downloaded source packages are in
#13 2077.7      ‘/tmp/downloaded_packages’
#13 2077.7 Error: installation of package ‘Robyn’ had non-zero exit status
#13 2077.7 In addition: Warning messages:
#13 2077.7 1: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#13 2077.7   installation of package ‘curl’ had non-zero exit status
#13 2077.7 2: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#13 2077.7   installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
#13 2077.7 3: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#13 2077.7   installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
#13 2077.7 4: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#13 2077.7   installation of package ‘openssl’ had non-zero exit status
#13 2077.7 5: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#13 2077.7   installation of package ‘h2o’ had non-zero exit status
#13 2077.7 6: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#13 2077.7   installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
#13 2077.7 7: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#13 2077.7   installation of package ‘rvest’ had non-zero exit status
#13 2077.7 8: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#13 2077.7   installation of package ‘lares’ had non-zero exit status
#13 2077.7 9: In install.packages(pkgs, ...) :
#13 2077.7   installation of package ‘Robyn’ had non-zero exit status
#13 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c install2.r --error --deps TRUE Robyn]: exit code: 1
------
 > [ 9/12] RUN install2.r --error --deps TRUE Robyn:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c install2.r --error --deps TRUE Robyn]: exit code: 1
```

---

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: What do the logs for the docker build say for the `install.packages("Robyn")` command?  You should check to see if it's successfully installed.

Comment: Hi,

This is the output for container logs when installing reticulate in R script directly:


`/bin/bash: line 1: libpng-config: command not found
 read.c:3:10: fatal error: png.h: No such file or directory
     3 | #include <png.h>
       |          ^~~~~~~
 compilation terminated.
 make: *** [/usr/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:168: read.o] Error 1
 ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘png’
 * removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/png’
 ERROR: dependency ‘png’ is not available for package ‘reticulate’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/reticulate’`

Comment: That looks like an error in the log for installing reticulate.  I think you'll need to install libpng Linux system library?  I don't know exactly.  What I do know: you'll have to read through the logs to see where the first error occurred and fix it.  Then build the container again with the fix and find the next error and fix it.  The fix is often to update or install system libraries that are required by the R and Python packages.

Comment: Of course you can.  But _if_ you decide to install from source, you all the build dependencies.  That is true for every build, Docker or nor, R or not, Python or not.  I am one of the maintainers of the Rocker project, you could start with our containers. I am a particular fan of the `rocker/r2u` container that allow you to install R packages as Ubuntu binries.  Give it a go:  https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u/   Binaries are generally much easier to use than source, but not always available for Linux.  `r2u` changes that for R and CRAN on Ubuntu.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Thanks for your reply. Yes, I did try `rocker/r-ubuntu`... still getting this: `ERROR: dependency ‘lares’ is not available for package ‘Robyn’`. Have updated the question with exact Dockerfile using `rocker`

Comment: `rocker/r-ubuntu` is not the same as `rocker/r2u`.  I recommended the latter.

Comment: Sure, let me try, thanks.

Comment: In the `r2u` container just call `install.r rjson reticulate Robyn` and these three CRAN packages with install with all their dependencies.  (I do not know if `reticulate` will need extra configuration or not; it is a somewhat complex package.)